# Why this subtable is shown undefined Control sequence

Tags: tables, subfloats

When i want to run this code, i got error about undefined control sequence in \subfloat tag. How can i solve it.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
   \subfloat[First Subtable\label{tab:chapter4:1a}]{
     \tiny
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
       a&b&c\\
       d&e&f\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
   }
   \subfloat[Second Subtable\label{tab:chapter4:1b}]{
     \tiny
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
       g&h&i\\
       j&k&l\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
   }
   \subfloat[Third Subtable\label{tab:chapter4:1c}]{
     \tiny
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
       m&n&o\\
       p&q&r\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
   }
   \caption{Testing}\label{tab:chapter4:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In standard article document class I can't reproduce your error. However, result is not nice ... Please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}\end{document}

Comment: Please edit your question and add this and other missed packages to your code fragment.

Comment: In your MWE (Minimal Working Example) is missed `\usepackage{subfig}` in its preamble.

Comment: But not still working after adding \usepackage{subfig} in document. other packages are given

Comment: you add `subfigure` (which not define `subfloat` and  it is also obsolete), not `subfig`.

Answer (score 1):

In your MWE (Minimal Working Example) you load package `subfigure`, which is obsolete and also not define environment `subfloat`. For it you nit to load `subfig` (observe difference in package's name). You should not load both packages!.

Try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{subfig}   % <--- missed package, it is not compatible with "subfigure" !
%\captionsetup[subfloat]{justification=RaggedRight}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
%\tiny
   \subfloat[First Subtable\label{tab:chapter4:1a}]{
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
       a&b&c\\
       d&e&f\\  \hline
     \end{tabular}
   }\hfil
   \subfloat[Second Subtable\label{tab:chapter4:1b}]{
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
       g&h&i\\
       j&k&l\\  \hline
     \end{tabular}
   }\hfil
   \subfloat[Third Subtable\label{tab:chapter4:1c}]{
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
       m&n&o\\
       p&q&r\\  \hline
     \end{tabular}
   }
   \caption{Testing}\label{tab:chapter4:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which works without any error and gives:

[image]

Comment: working :). Thanks a lot Zarko.